# Run LUA in STM32F103 throw an error "unexpected symbol"

Tags: lua, stm32

I have successfully built LUA in STM32F103, and the code below is OK:

```
const char lua_test[] = "print(\"Hello Lua!!\")";
lua_State *L;  
L = luaL_newstate();   
luaL_openlibs(L);  
luaopen_base(L);  
luaL_dostring(L, lua_test);   
lua_close(L);
```

The string shows in serial port properly.
But when I put print function into a file in external SD card and try replacing "dostring" into "dofile" like this:

```
lua_State *L;  
L = luaL_newstate(); 
luaL_openlibs(L);  
luaopen_base(L);  

if (luaL_dofile(L, "1:/2.txt")!=0) //Run 2.txt in SD card
      USART1_Send_String(lua_tostring(L,-1));
lua_close(L);
```

Serial port show an error message "1:/2.txt:1: unexpected symbol" and the function "luaL_dofile" returns 3.
The error message doesn't contain any hint like "near XXX".

I have overrided "_sys_open" and "_sys_read" and am sure that the file "1:/2.txt" is read properly.
I tried to change the content of 2.txt into anything including a new line and a space only, but still got same error.

How to fix this problem or how can I get further error message?
Please help me, any advice is appreciative.

PS: I am using official lua 5.3.4. It requires at least 7.5KB RAM and 65K ROM. I allocate 4KB stack and 16K heap in internal 64KB RAM of STM32F103ZET6. Running lua code by "luaL_dostring" works fine, but got error when calling "luaL_dofile".

Comment: Is it stock Lua (from lua.org) or a modified version of Lua?

Comment: So, your device has 96 KBytes of RAM?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff I am using official lua 5.3.4. It requires at least 7.5KB RAM and 65K ROM. I allocate 4KB stack and 16K heap in internal 64KB RAM of STM32F103ZET6. Running lua code by "luaL_dostring" works fine, but got error when calling "luaL_dofile".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried overriding "fgetc" instead of "_sys_read" and it works. But I think that read file one character by one character may cause bad performance of IO.
Finally I find that the return value of "_sys_read" should be the length that remain to be read rather than have been read. After correcting the  "_sys_read" function like below, the "luaL_dofile" function now runs properly.

```
int _sys_read(FILEHANDLE fh, unsigned char*buf, unsigned len, int mode)
{
  FRESULT fr;
  UINT br;  
  fr = f_read((FIL *)fh, buf, len, &br);
  if (fr == FR_OK)
    return len - br;
  return -1;
}
```